# How to fetch Latitude and Longitude of 5 Nearby Places from Google Maps API using PHP JSON object?

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-nearby

I am using Google Maps API to fetch Nearby Places for a given Location (Latitude, Longitude).

I have done it as follows:

```
<?php
    $du = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=APIKEY");
    $djd = json_decode(utf8_encode($du),true);
    print_r($djd);
?>
```

This returns a JSON file in the browser.

I want to know how to fetch the [latitude, longitude] of first 5 restaurants returned in the JSON, so that I can use them to plot a marker on the map display?

I am new to PHP and unable to parse the JSON object. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the JSON that comes back (abbreviated):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CrQCIQEA...",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.87036190000001,
               "lng" : 151.1978505
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8690162197085,
                  "lng" : 151.1991288802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8717141802915,
                  "lng" : 151.1964309197085
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "e58f0f9ecaf15ab719d305b93265cafc00b01a3f",
         "name" : "The Little Snail Restaurant",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 900,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/114727320476039103791/photos\"\u003eThe Little Snail Restaurant\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA0I3YolUFMPSLTtWTRwwDN8TrsmfORJ36osMasP6PeqJSp4qIxdmn3hs6FNifT6Wf-1rZ_gwr1C7a8U1-3BVXhL9suX3cs1ffJiBJQ5TswKftrlLRAk9F9a6tuHpQ1KhrEhD1QXDGR2Sao1qKG5hqvnsVGhTDTxrJvlfSn5UetP261FuHpHmTTQ",
               "width" : 1350
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJtwapWjeuEmsRcxV5JARHpSk",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "45HX+V4 Pyrmont, New South Wales, Australia",
            "global_code" : "4RRH45HX+V4"
         },
         "price_level" : 2,
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "ChIJtwapWjeuEmsRcxV5JARHpSk",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 931,
         "vicinity" : "3/50 Murray Street, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.8682215,
               "lng" : 151.1953756
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.8670561697085,
                  "lng" : 151.1962794802915
               }...
```

Just navigate your way through the hierarchy you see above. Let's call the whole JSON object `response`...

`response.results` is an array with all of the matches that have been found.

You want to keep the first 5 items in this array, so you can do this:

`let top5 = response.results.slice(0, 5)`

For the first matching result, the latitude and longitude are:

`top5[0].geometry.location.lat`,
`top5[0].geometry.location.lng`

PS: Sorry this answer uses JavaScript syntax, not PHP, but I hope it's enough to give you an idea what to do!

Answer (score 0):

kshetline answered your question the way you would interact with the JSON object in JavaScript, but since you never mentioned JavaScript and only have PHP in your question's tags I am going to try to answer you with PHP.

To access properties of a JSON object in PHP, you must use the [arrow syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp):

```
$result = $djd->results;
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    // Do what you want with them from here
    $lat = $result[$i]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $result[$i]->geometry->location->lng;

    // Example of how to return them
    echo json_encode($lat);
    echo json_encode($lng);
}
```

I do not know what the JSON returned looks like, so I based my PHP off of the JSON in kshetline's answer. I'm sure their JSON is correct, so this should work.